# Question about ようにと

Tags: grammar

Could somebody please explain me the grammar in ようにと. Is there something omitted between ように and と?

As far as I can guess the author is saying something like - "For now I'll try to not think about anything, and continue reading the letter."

> 手紙は続く。いまは何も考えないようにと努め、私は次へと進む。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about parsing it as:

> 『いまは何も考えないように』と努め、私は次へと進む。

or

> 『いまは何も考えないように(しよう。)』と努め、私は次へと進む。

So I think your translation is correct.